# undefined reference to `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_' in gcc 32-bit code for a trivial function, freestanding OS

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, osdev, got

I have a small c code file(function.c):

```
int function()
{
    return 0x1234abce;
}
```

I am using a 64 bit machine. However, I want to write a small 32 bit OS. I want to compile the code into a 'pure' assembly/binary file.

I compile my code with:

`gcc function.c -c -m32 -o file.o -ffreestanding   # This gives you the object file`

I link it with:

`ld -o function.bin -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0x0 --oformat binary function.o`

I am getting the following error:

```
function.o: In function `function':
function.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
```

Comment: There's a section about Global Offset Table in https://wiki.osdev.org/Dynamic_Linker, which might help you understanding the underlying what and why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need `-fno-pie`**; the [default (in most modern distros) is `-fpie`: generate code for a position-independent executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux).  This is a code-gen option separate from the `-pie` linker option (which gcc also passes by default), and is independent of `-ffreestanding`.  `-fpie -ffreestanding` implies you want a freestanding PIE that uses a GOT, so that's what GCC targets.

`-fpie` only costs a bit of speed in 64-bit code (where RIP-relative addressing is possible) but is quite bad for 32-bit code; compilers get a pointer to the GOT in one of the integer registers (tying up another one of the 8) and access static data relative to that address with `[reg + disp32]` addressing modes like `[eax + foo@GOTOFF]`

---

**With optimization disabled, `gcc -fpie -m32` generates the address of the GOT in a register** even though the function doesn't access any static data.  You'd can see this if you look at your compiler output (with `gcc -S` instead of `-c` on the machine you're compiling on).

[On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+function()%0A%7B%0A++++return+0x1234abce%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:45.58724883600972,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O0+-fpie+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:54.41275116399028,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) we can use `-m32 -fpie` to give the same effect as a GCC configured with `--enable-default-pie`:

```
# gcc9.2 -O0 -m32 -fpie
function():
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp                        # frame pointer
        call    __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax
        add     eax, OFFSET FLAT:_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_  # EAX points to the GOT
        mov     eax, 305441742                  # overwrite with the return value
        pop     ebp
        ret

__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax:          # this is the helper function gcc calls
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp]
        ret
```

The "thunk" returns its return address.  i.e. the address of the instruction after the `call`.  The `.ax` name means to return in EAX.  Modern GCC can choose any register; traditionally the 32-bit PIC base register was always EBX but modern GCC chooses a call-clobbered register when that avoids an extra save/restore of EBX.

Fun fact: `call +0; pop eax` would be more efficient, and only 1 byte larger at each call site.  You might think that would unbalance the return-address predictor stack, but in fact `call +0` is special-cased on most CPUs to not do that.  http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/#call0.  (`call +0` means the rel32 = 0, so it calls the next instruction.  That's not how NASM would interpret that syntax, though.)

clang doesn't generate a GOT pointer unless it needs one, even at `-O0`.  But it does so with `call +0`;`pop %eax`: https://godbolt.org/z/GFY9Ht

Comment: @SuraajKS: you can let everyone know that by clicking the accept checkbox under the vote arrows.

Comment: PeterCordes, I was looking back at this answer.... Consider a simple 16 bit assembly snippet like this:  * bits 16 ; call +0; pop ax; jmp $ ; * . I emulate using qemu. The program crashes... Maybe instead of call +0, you meant ```call nextLabel  ; nextLabel: ``` ?

Comment: @SuraajKS: `call +0` is intended to indicate a `rel32`=0 in the actual machine-code encoding.  But if you assemble it with NASM `+0` is absolute address 0.  `call $+5` would be one way to write it for NASM in 32/64-bit mode, or with labels like you showed.  But that doesn't highlight the fact that the actual adjustment to EIP/RIP is 0.  So once you understand what `call +0` means, it's very nice notation.  Maybe I need to add some explanation to the answer if that wasn't obvious to everyone else, though.

Comment: Aha... Understood @PeterCordes

Answer (score 3):

By default, your compiler creates a [position-independant executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

You can force your compiler to build a non-pie executable by passing the option `-fno-pie`.